# Can I filter an array of objects from state and then render them?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to filter products from my state and then render them on the page.

The idea is to compare the products.user_id and make sure it matches my currently logged in user.user_id and then render only the products that pass.

I'm trying have one view on page with all products in total, and the view next to it would have all of the specific logged in user's products.

I have attempted a bunch of different combinations of filter, but i think the main issue im having is finding how to use render with the filter function.

With map, you can just map the different properties directly onto the page and pass them down as props for example to be rendered, but with filter, it doesn't user the same syntax. I could be wrong though.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { get_user, get_products } from '../../ducks/reducer';
import axios from 'axios';

class SellerProducts extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        products: []
    };
}
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.get_user();
    // console.log('specific user product', this.props.get_products());

    axios.get('/api/product').then(res => {
        // console.log('Get all products (SellerProducts', res);
        this.setState({ products: res.data });
        console.log('SellerProducts products', this.state.products);
    });
    console.log('sellerproduct component mount user', this.props.user);
}
render() {
    let sellersItems = [];

    // if (this.state.products.length > 0) {
    //  sellersItems = this.state.products.filter((products, i) => {
    //      console.log('incoming array',products)
    //      return products[i].user_id === this.props.user.user_id;
    //  });
    // }
    if (this.props.loggedIn === false) {
        return (
            <div className="product_container">
                <div>
                    {sellersItems}
                    <div>
                        {this.props.product_name}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        {this.props.info}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        {this.props.product_type}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img
                            className="sellerProductImages"
                            src={this.props.img_url}
                            alt={this.props.product_type}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
    if (this.state.products.length > 0 && this.props.loggedin === true) {
        sellersItems = this.state.products.filter((products, i) => {
            console.log('incoming array', products);
            return products[i].user_id === this.props.user.user_id;
            return {
                products[i].user_id === this.props.user.user_id;

            } 

        });
    }
}
}
const mapStateToProps = state => state;

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
get_user,
get_products
})(SellerProducts);
```

Comment: It looks like you are filtering the items into sellersItems. Why do you not just map over sellerItems after that to render the values?

Comment: `filter` will create a new array with all the elements that returned a truthy value from the function given to it. You can then use `map` on this new array.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone! I wasn't thinking about having to map after i filter in order to render everything! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning the items in the second block
Also you are returning twice. Removed in the block below

```
   var sellersItems = this.state.products.filter((products, i) => { // <-----
        console.log('incoming array', products);
        return products[i].user_id === this.props.user.user_id;
    });

    return sellersItems.map(item => {
       // However you want to display the items
       return <div> {item.user_id} </div>
    })
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you! I forgot i can map over the new filtered array afterwards!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are pretty much there. You are correct that you cannot directly render from filter, but you generated your filtered list that you can then just map over.

```
if (this.state.products.length > 0 && this.props.loggedin === true) {
    sellersItems = this.state.products.filter((products, i) => {
        console.log('incoming array', products);
        return products[i].user_id === this.props.user.user_id; 
    });
    sellersItems.map(item => (<span>{item.name}</span))
}
```

Comment: This makes sense! I wasn't thinking about mapping over the new filtered array!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a jsx element inside the filter like this:

```js
if (this.state.products.length > 0 && this.props.loggedin === true) {
    sellersItems = this.state.products.filter((products, i) => {
        console.log('incoming array', products);
     if( products[i].user_id === this.props.user.user_id ){
       return <span> { products[i].name } </span>
     } 
    });
}
```

This way you just iterate one time through all your products instead of filtering and then mapping in separete iterations.